# New/Update Date onEdit Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script for Google sheets that automatically enters a date value when the cell value adjacent matches certain criteria. The script is as follows:

```
function onEdit() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var value = cell.getValue();
  var col2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col+1);
  if (col == 11 && (value=="Declined" || value=="Accepted" || 
value=="Completed" || value=="Withdrawn"))
    return col2.setValue(new Date());
}
```

This works absolutely perfectly the first time that the value is entered (eg blank to Declined). However when it updates again – eg from Declined to Withdrawn, the date remains the same as the first time the value was changed.

What do I need to add/change to make sure that the date is updated every time the cell value changes, rather than just the first time?

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1):

The script seems to be working fine. Make sure the column with the timestamp is formatted as Date/time (so you can actually see the difference when changes are made within the same day).

Here's an alternative version

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.columnStart == 11 && !!~["Declined", "Accepted", "Completed", "Withdrawn"].indexOf(e.value))
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(new Date())
}
```